# PHP exec doesn't get stdout after long execution

Tags: php, c, exec, stdout

I got a program written in C and compiled with gcc, which I've tested for memory leaks etc in both Linux with Valgrind and in Windows with drmemory, and that with the relevant problematic argv arguments. I've found absolutely no problem doing so, and I get the output I expect when doing so. The only libraries included, and barely used are, stdio.h, stdlib.h, string.h, sys/time.h. Only output is printf and fopen to a specific file, which of course is closed after use, no messing with around with stdout or stderr or something like that.

I call this program from PHP with exec, and the program seems to work perfectly almost all the time, except for some few times when the executable takes like 30+ seconds or something along those lines. The problem is then that it seems I don't get the stdout that I should get assigned to the $output argument with the PHP exec function call, neither does it return anything, which should be the last line outputted from the program. The return value argument for the exec function gets set to 0, which really is the only return value the main function in the C program is set to return, there's no exit or anything else. I've of course set the time limit of the PHP script to 0, and it can run for hours just fine. Should also be noted I run this PHP script from cmd.exe in Windows 7 with administrator privileges.

I've been debugging this so much now, and before I decided to post here, I wanted to see if it actually got to the printf part of my program where the output I want should be printed, so I made it write the exact same string to file right after the printf. Guess what? It wrote the expected result to that file......

From this I take it that PHP exec somehow don't get the stdout output after a certain amount of time. Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

I guess a possible fix is to make the PHP script check the created file for the output instead of getting it through the $output argument that should get it from stdout. Perhaps do this when it gets nothing from $output, but this seems like a very shabby workaround.

Is there some kind of setting I've missed?

I'm running PHP 5.6.6.

EDIT:
I've also already made sure to set this at the start of the PHP script before I even started doing any of the tests etc:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to extend the maximum execution time in your server configuration (or by using set_time_limit())? The default one is 30 as I remember correctly. Maybe this causes the problems.

Comment: As I said in the question post, "I've of course set the time limit of the PHP script to 0, and it can run for hours just fine.". I've tested it running for a half day before, and it does this just fine. It's also not a server, I run it on my local computer in cmd.exe, as specified in the question.

Comment: Do you get a lot of output or use a lot of memory? Maybe it is the memory limit that causes the problem?

Comment: No, while the program does use a lot of CPU cycles, it doesn't take a lot of memory, like some few hundred kB or whatever. Pretty much nothing. I think this is a bug with PHP, so I probably should report it to Zend

Comment: Do you get any errors or warning in your servers errors log file?

Comment: Again, I'm not running it on a server. I'm running it in the terminal on Windows 7 (cmd.exe) on my own computer. I've set it to report all errors (E_ALL), but I get nothing, and I usually get errors in the terminal each time there's an actual error.

Comment: :/ ok but on your computer you have something like apache or other software? Or if not then you at least have had installed a php right? So you can go and find some log files about the executions you run on your local computer and then let us know.

Comment: No, I've not installed Apache. I have only packed out a file containing a pre-compiled php executable and other relevant files for Windows. I've not set PHP to log errors in a file, the same ones should be printed to the terminal. It doesn't seem PHP treats it as an error, whatsoever.

Comment: OK then I cannot help you remotely with so little info. I wish you luck with this one :)

Comment: I suspect something like the "link" file that PHP makes the C program redirect stdout to to only exist temporary or something like that. I've made sure to add a new line character at the end of the output, but that did little good. I honestly suspect this to be a PHP bug, so I will just work with the workaround, because that works. :p

Comment: If you want to help or test etc, you can write a simple C program which only sleeps for 1 minute or something then prints something to stdout using printf, then return. How does php exec react to that for you?

Comment: I will try when I will have some more free time. The one thing makes me very cutrious. You said you use exec and get direct output from it right? That's weird becouse normaly exec() function buffers the output and can give it to you only by giving some buffer to it. Did you try to replace this function with system() function? Who knows maybe that will help :)

Comment: Because you said that, I went to look at the documentation for that function... Somebody seems to have had the exact same problem as I. They seemed to have fixed it by adding ' 2>&1' to the command name or whatever. :o Might try that then, but not sure exactly how that will work with the already very specified amount of arguments. :p

Comment: I will keep my thumbs for you with it :)

Comment: Well, that didn't do much good. I guess I will have to pass the value through a file then, but I guess that's kind what it does anyways. ;) I tried system too.